# try-catch-finally and rest of the method order of execution

Tags: java, exception

I've got a doubt about using the try/catch/finally clauses,let me explain:
I know that every method which declares an exception specification in its declaration has to be surrounded (in a calling method) with a try block,followed by a catch block that can capture that exception (unless I don't declare the calling method throwing an exception as well). If the calling method has other statements after the try-catch, those are executed regardless of what happens (exception thrown or not). So if I have the following code:

```
 public class ExceptionCall {
   Throwing t = new Throwing();
    public void methodTry(){
        while(true){
            try {
                if (t.flag++==0)
                    t.throwing();
                System.out.println("no exception");
            } 
            catch (MyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                System.out.println("working on it!");
            }
            finally{
                System.out.println("finally clause");
            }
                System.out.println("out");
                if (t.flag==2) 
                    break;  
        }
    }
}
```

Here `Throwing` has a method called (guess what :) ) throwing() which is declared to throw a `MyException exception`, and has a public field called flag containing an int initialized to 0 to provide a sort of condition checking.

So for a couple of times the code outside the guarded region is executed no matter what happens in the try block.

So my question is, what is the finally block for?? I mean, I know it comes in handy when the calling method returns from the try or the catch block (in this case I could have a break statement inside the catch and the finally would be executed), but in a case like this what's the difference??

Comment: Since your catch doesn't break you out of your loop or even your method (no `return`, `break`, not re-throwing), the finally isn't really needed here. One usage of `finally` may be to clean up something you did in the `try` that would otherwise be leaked or left to the GC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally block is used to handle those resources that need you to make some action at the end of the statement no matter what happens in the code.

For example: readers or streams are resources that must be closed after it's use, but exceptions can happen during it's usage, so where you close them???

Here is where `finally` clause becomes really handy:

```
FileReader reader;

try {
  reader = new FileReader("someNonExistingFile");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // handle FileNotFoundException
   e.printMessage();
} finally {
   // reader MUST BE CLOSED ALWAYS, so FINALLY, CLOSE IT
   reader.close();
}
```

In this example, you need to close reader always (if file exists and if file doesn't) so, instead of closing it twice (in `try` and in `catch`) you use `finally`.

Further info and examples of finally [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html). Also check [try with resources](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html) (Java 7+).

Comment: your code doesn't work, reader is in the scope of the try block and cant be seen inside the finally. Also, it can't be initialized inside the try, cause the compiler don't let me close it (it could not have been opened in the first place).
In this case I could write the cleanup code outside the finally and it would be executed the same wouldn't it?

Comment: sorry, modified... it was wexample written on the fly! but you get the idea??

Comment: yes I get it..but wouldn't a code outside finally be executed as well? (in this case)

Comment: in this simple case yes, but there are plenty of scenarios: i.e: execution breaks when exception happens, some reference gets null and candidate to GC.... in the link I share you will find plenty cases by Lars Vogel, one of better java tutorial makers

Answer (score 5):

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.

See : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html